# Proof about complex exponential function forming an infinite dimensional vector space

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Okay, so I sort of understand what is going on here. this has to do with the fact that the exponential function is bijective over this interval, yes?

Either way, I have no idea where to start with this one. This problem is really intimidating.. (also I don't think I can use euler's formula to expand that function, since we haven't covered it.)

Comment: Hint: Orthogonality.

Comment: This is the complex exponential. It is not bijective at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $e^{ikx}$ can be written as a finite linear combination of $e^{ik_nx}$ where $k_n \neq k$ for any $n$. Write down the linear combination and then multiply by $e^{-ikx}$ and then integrate from $0$ to $2\pi$ and see what you get.

Comment: okay I will try this, thank you.

Comment: do you think i'd be allowed to integrate it "regularly" in an analysis class? we've only covered integration up to proving the FTC so far.

Comment: actually, how DO I even integrate the right hand side? left hand side is obviously just $x$, but the right hand side every single term is a product of exponentials.

Comment: Right, but every exponential on the right-hand side will have the form $c_n e^{(k_n - k)ix$, where $k_n - k \neq 0$. You can integrate each term and then sum, and you should get $0$.

Comment: thank you, user2566092. I did this out, and I got $2\pi = 0$, which is obviously a contradiction. :)

Comment: @user2566092 can you expound on your answer a little more? I was trying to follow and practice these problems, but was not able to do it myself. How do you write it as a linear combination with only 1 function?